# Detect the choice of a user in a list

Tags: jquery

When a user choose the "a" option in the first list below (id=1), I'd like to display the second form (id=2). How detect the choice of a user in a list (just a selection, not a submission) ?

```
 <form method="post" id="1" >
      <select name="menu_destination">
           <option value="a" >A</option>
           <option value="b">B</option>
      </select>
 </form>

 <form method="post" id="2" >
      <select name="menu_destination">
           <option value="a" >A</option>
           <option value="b">B</option>
      </select>
 </form>
```

Edit: I've already encounter another problem : each time I select an option, it displays a list without hiding the others. annoying, no ?

```
$("select#category").change(function() {
    var category = $(this).val();
    $("select#"+category).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. And IDs should not start with numbers, at least not until HTML5 is all over the place.

```
$("#one select").change(function() {
    $("#two").toggle($(this).val() == "a");
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6J4f/)

Note: In the demo, the second form's visibility is initially hidden via `style="display:none"` but it is *visible* when the page loads because we initially *trigger* the change event to set the correct state of the form according to the what is initially selected (i.e. what is initially rendered) in the first form's drop-down.

Comment: +1 for the boolean argument to `toggle` which everyone seems to forget about!

Comment: Thanks but what I have to do to detect what value choosed the user ? I'd like to get the value option he selected.

Comment: You forget the () : ( $(this).val() ). Perfect dude thanks a lot.

Comment: @Anon - I did, sorry! Glad I could help!